# Mockito- Unable to throw exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, static, mockito

I have static void method() that calls write(byte[]) of ByteArrayOutputStream.

I want the write(byte[]) to throw an IOException. I throw a new custom exception from method() when an IOException occurs.
I tried mocking ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
TestClass

   test() {
      ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = Mockito.mock(ByteArrayOutputStream.class);
      Mockito.dothrow(new IOException()).when(outputStream ).write(somebyte[]);`
      ClassA.method();
      ...
   }
```

The above doesn't throw exception, but if I call outputStream .write(somebyte[]) in test() the exception get thrown. why wouldn't it mock the ByteArrayOutputStream inside ClassA.method()?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How does `method` get the `OutputStream` does it open its own one?

Comment: How does your `outputStream` get into `ClassA`?

Comment: We can't answer your question in its current form, there are too many unknowns. Perhaps you should expand your code example to be compilable code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Mureink, yes there is a new ByteArrayOutputStream in ClassA.method()

Comment: Can you give us [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

You must write the same somebyte[] object as you use in mock. Mockito ignores the call if the argument is different

If you don't have the reference to the object, use 'any' matcher.

```
Mockito.doThrow(new IOException())
    .when(outputStream).write(Matchers.any(byte[].class));
```

Comment: `OutputStream` has a number of overloaded write() methods. Are you sure  it `write(byte[])` is called?